# pandas extractall matching

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas

How can I match the below with a pandas extractall regex:

```
stringwithinmycolumn
stuff, Duration: 15h:22m:33s, notstuff,
stuff, Duration: 18h:22m:33s, notstuff,
```

Currently, I am using the below:

```
df.message.str.extractall(r',([^,]*?): ([^,:]*?,').reset_index()
```

Expected output:

```
              0              1
match    
    0  Duration    15h:22m:33s
    1  Duration    18h:22m:33s
```

I am not able to match so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [246]: x.message.str.extractall(r',\s*(\w+):\s*([^,]*)').reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
Out[246]:
              0            1
match
0      Duration  15h:22m:33s
0      Duration  18h:22m:33s
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
,\s*([^,:]+):\s*([^,]+),
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rYxt4Q/2)

It matches:

- `,`  - a comma
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `([^,:]+)` - Group 1:  - 0+ chars other than `,` and `:`
- `:` - a colon
- `\s*`  - 0+ whitespaces
- `([^,]+)` - Group 2: one or more chars other than `,`
- `,`  - a comma (this actually can be removed, but may stay to ensure safer matching.)

Note that you may consider making your regex more precise when you need to extract structured information from long strings. So, you may want to use letter matching pattern to match `Duration`, and only digits, colon, `h`, `m` or `s` to extract the time value. So, the pattern will become a bit more verbose:

```
,\s*([A-Za-z]+):\s*([\d:hms]+)
```

but much safer. See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LpFNxp/1).